# Converting mathematical formula into node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, formula, bioinformatics

I want to use the mathematical formula as listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_bracelets

in node.js to calculate the total number of unique ring sequences I can generate of `n` length using `k` characters, allowing for repetition, and ignoring mirrored sequences

This formula requires the previous formula also be calculated, as listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_necklaces

The results of this "Number of necklaces" formula is used as `Nk(n)` in the "Number of bracelets" formula.

**EDIT**

here is the final solution:

```
const phi = require('number-theory').eulerPhi
const divisors = require('number-theory').divisors

let n = 6,
  k = 5,
  sum = (arr, func) => arr.reduce( (acc, n) => acc + func(n), 0),
  divisorsArray = divisors(n),
  necklaces = (1/n) * sum(divisorsArray, (d) => phi(d) * k ** (n/d))

let bracelets = (n % 2) ?
  (necklaces/2) + 0.5 * (k ** ((n+1)/2)) :
  (necklaces/2) + 0.25 * (k+1) * (k ** (n/2))
```

Comment: You can use a maths library like this one: https://github.com/arguiot/TheoremJS

Comment: thanks for the tip, but i dont understand the mathematical formula enough to even begin to see how to convert it into TheoremJS, or js of any sort? any advice?

Comment: I don't understand the formula too ^^. I can show you how to create a sum in js (that will be a good start):

const sum = (nStart, nEnd, myFunction) => {
  return Array.from(Array(nEnd - nStart)) // creating an empty array of x element
    .reduce((acc, item, n) => acc + myFunction(n))
  // check reduce function
}

sum(0, 100, n => n + 1)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation This explanation of sigma notation eventually describes exactly the use which confused you.

Comment: Questions about maths notation might get better answers on [math.se]. It is always helpful to mention exactly what part you don't understand, as you did here.

Comment: right so then that first formula for Necklaces, is basically:

`(1 /  n)` times the sum of all `(ϕ(d) * k * (n / d))` where `d` is all numbers that divide into `n`?

given that `n` is sequence length and `k` is number of possible characters

Comment: Please see the edited post, I think im on the right track but not quite there

Comment: Your `sum` function is incorrect. It should start with 0, not `arr[0]`. Since arr[0] is always 1 here, it computes the sum plus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution, which works correctly for me

```
const phi = require('number-theory').eulerPhi
const divisors = require('number-theory').divisors

let n = 6,
    k = 5,
    sum = (arr, func) => arr.reduce( (acc, n) => acc + func(n), 0),
    divisorsArray = divisors(n),
    necklaces = (1/n) * sum(divisorsArray, (d) => phi(d) * k ** (n/d))

let bracelets = (n % 2) ?
    (necklaces/2) + 0.5 * (k ** ((n+1)/2)) :
    (necklaces/2) + 0.25 * (k+1) * (k ** (n/2))
```

Comment: As noted in a comment to your question, you wouldn't need Math.floor if you computed the sum correctly :)

Comment: that doesnt seem to be right, if i remove the `arr[0]` from the sum, for k: 5, n: 5 i get 64, but if i put the `arr[0]` back i get 377 (the correct answer)

Comment: The solution is not to just remove `arr[0]` (which will give you a different wrong value). You need to replace it with 0.

Comment: ah right, my bad, thanks for that, updated my code to reflect that

Comment: Alternatively, `necklaces = divisorsArray.map(d => phi(d) * k ** (n/d)).reduce((a,n) => a+n) / n`. (In this case, it's better to divide at the end because that computation is exact, whereas `1/n` is not except for powers of 2.) The reduce/map idiom works better in languages (like Python) in which map is a generator; in JS, map creates a temporary array.

Comment: I would recommend you refactor the formulas into `const`, since they are not to be changed and are never expected to change, outside of the variables passed in.